# Sorry for a dumb question. How to create a random sample of size e.g. 10 individuals in R

Tags: r

[image: The id represents a person]

How do I create a random sample df of 10 PEOPLE in R?

Comment: What is the picture supposed to represent? What have you tried so far? The manual page for the `sample()` function may be helpful, `?sample`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sample. the first criteria is the range or list of numbers that it will randomly pick. the second number is the amount of numbers to pick

```
sample(1:100, 10)
```

[image: Random sample of 10]